# He does not perform the procedure. Fail in first step. Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I created procedure in oracle that drops my table and creates same table from my view. But I have some problems with running this procedure. First step with drop table works but copying it doesn't work.

It this a good procedure ?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE transfer_table (table_name IN VARCHAR2,tableFrom IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || table_name || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || tableFrom;
  commit;
END transfer_table;
```

Next I click on this procedure and change the variable then view and click ok, but only the first step of dropping the table is working. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: No but table doesn't create :/ maybe is a problem with credential.

Comment: Maybe a simple typo? Does a table or view named AUTOMAT_CENY_ODTW really exist? (Commit and rollback have no effect on DDL commands like CREATE and DROP, by the way.)

Comment: Look into materialized views.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to catch the error if the table you are creating doesn't exist.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE transfer_table (table_name IN VARCHAR2,tableFrom IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || table_name || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || tableFrom;
  commit;
END transfer_table;
```